# How to provide number format:percentage for some cells in a table while exporting from SSRS to Excel

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a table in SSRS 2008, which I manually typed the values for each cell like:

```
Name    Age    Ratio
Jack    15     50%
John    20     35%
...
```

My problem is, when I export the table into Excel after the report is executed, the ratio values are not coming as "percentage", so it seems like below and it becomes required for the user to change the cell format to do any process on the number.

[image]

So the green arrows at the left corner should not be there and the values would be in percentage format. I could not find how to fix it. I tried: `Right click to the cell in ssrs -> Textbox properties -> Number -> Percentage` for all the cells but it did not fix the issue. I also tried to assign custom formats like "#,0%", "#%"  etc., but it also did not solve. It seems basic, but I am kinda stuck. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Edit: After comments, I tried the advises and the result in excel:
[image]

1. I left the content as it is and made the format "P0"
2. Changed the content by removing % sign and different format of numbers. but In excel, all were texts :(

Comment: Putting `P0` in the Format property works fine for me, is not it for you?

Comment: If you have `50%` in a table then it is **text** because of the **percent sign**. Your table data should have `.5` in order to allow for numeric formatting.

Comment: I tried your advises, and added the result to the question. Not solved yet:(

Comment: Hmm...are you still using a text field for the number? If you just have the field in your expression, try converting to decimal with =CDEC(Fields!YourField.Value) to see if that helps.

Comment: There is no value coming from a query, I am writing all the values manually myself. There is a table, it has a column named Ratio. Should I write like CDEC("22")& "%" in this case, for example?

Answer (score 0):

Use expressions for the values as decimals, e.g. `=0.22`. The results of these equations will be treated as numbers, unlike when you type a value into a text box.

In the Text Box Properties of the cells, in the Number options, choose the Percentage category. This uses a format of `0.00%`, rather than `P0`.

Testing this with SSRS 2008 R2 and Excel 2013 seems to give the desired effect, as the green arrows are missing and you can insert formulas without adjusting the exported cells.